# How can I access individual element in array of sheets and avoid Run-time error 9 - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variant array of sheets based on sheet names listed in a column (named range "SheetRange") using the Application.Transpose method. This array is valid and works with the Sheets().Select method, but when I try to assign the value of an element (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-function)), it gives Runtime Error 9 - Subscript out of Range.

Is there something fundamental I'm missing here? Does the assignment via the Application.Transpose method change the array type such that it can't be worked with as normal?

Here is my code:

```
Sub SheetArrayTest()
Dim SheetArray As Variant
Dim IndividualSheet As String
SheetArray = Application.Transpose(ActiveWorkbook.Names("SheetRange").RefersToRange.Value)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetArray).Select 'This function works!
IndividualSheet = SheetArray(0) 'This function throws Runtime error 9 Subscript out of range
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SheetArray(0)` does not exist, because in VBA first array value has index 1 (not 0). Calling `IndividualSheet = SheetArray(1)` should work just fine.

To see what values you have in your array, in VBA Editor click  View -> Locals window. In the debug mode you can then easily click and see values for all your variables, including arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much! The Locals window is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**Range Collections** (and VB Collections in general) **are one based.** (This is not due to the `Transpose` function).

`Dim coll As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection()`

- This `Collection` object is one-based, which means that the index values of the elements range from 1 through the value of the `Count` property. Visual Basic collections hold elements of type `Object`.
  [learn.microsoft.com: Collection Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2)

There are 3 main types of grouping constructs available in VBA, with distinctions between indexes.
[Superuser - which excel objects are zero based and which are one based](https://superuser.com/questions/988321/which-excel-objects-are-zero-based-and-which-are-one-based)

1. Collections - 1-based index
2. Arrays - 0-based by default, but the first index can be changed to any number
3. Dictionaries - not indexed, but indexes can be simulated with Keys

Comment: Thank you - this was going to be my exact follow up question! Lots of good info here.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Application.Transpose` returns a 1-based array.

So `SheetArray(1)` to access the first element of the array should work (assuming `SheetArray` is a one dimensional array).

Comment: Is there documentation for this effect? If you do a watch on `ActiveWorkbook.Names("SheetRange")` and drill down to RefersToRange.Value you will see indexes of 1, 2, .... This is all before `Transpose` is applied.

Comment: @TedD., I can't comment on `WorksheetFunction.Transpose`'s internal implementation and can't find anything relevant in its documentation, but from what I can see/test, `TRANSPOSE` does convert 0-based arrays to 1-based arrays in VBA (irrespective of what `Option Base` is set to). This is probably because it's a worksheet function designed primarily for ranges (which, as you've already said, are 1-based). My answer could have been better worded though.

Comment: Agree: Worksheet being one based, Transpose returns one based. An even bigger oddity of Transpose is used by the OP; Making a two dimensional array, a one dimensional array, when the second dimension's size is one. It also works the other way (given a one dimensional array, returns a 2 dimensional array).